# Php while codes show just 1 row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using these codes.

```
$blog = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id");

while($sutun = mysql_fetch_array($blog)) {
    $fake = $sutun["date"];
    echo "$fake"; 
}
```

When i use `echo"$fake";` I can see all of my rows. But when I use `<?php echo "$fake" ?>` , It shows just 1 row for me.

I want to all of my rows while I'm using `<?php echo "$fake" ?>`.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. They are also insecure. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: You don't need to put the variable in quotes when you're going to echo it.

Comment: If you echo the variable after the loop, you will only get the last value, since you're overwriting the variable on each iteration.

Comment: So what can I do ? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: It depends on what you are going to do with the values after? You might want to build an array with the values to be able to loop through them later, or you might want to append them to the variable (all in one string), depending on what your end game is.

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse The `echo"$fake";` in with in a loop it will echo at every iteration thats why you can see all your rows  but `<?php echo"$fake"; ?>` executed when the loop is done so only the last row will be echoed;

Comment: If you want to use the variable $fake outside of the while loop, consider using arrays.

**$fake[] = $sutun["date"];**

and outside of the array, you may use **print_r($fake);**

Answer (score -1):

You should seperate your logic like

```
<?php
$blog = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id");

while($sutun = mysql_fetch_array($blog)) {

$fake = $sutun["date"];
?>
<?php
echo $fake;
}
```

Comment: why not, till now it is valid

Comment: @ManozBiswas - Since it can't handle Prepared Statements, it is prone to SQL Injection attacks (yes, even if you escape the user input).

Comment: Yes, I know pdo or mysqli is better to use nowadays, but your suggestion is not relevant to this question

Comment: Doesn't matter. Promoting insecure methods is always bad and should _always_ be pointed out. Specially to people with less experience. That's how people learn.